# What is used for holding String values in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, int

hi I would just like to ask

if Val(Textbox1.Text) is for holding values of integers.
what should I put when holding values for String??

Comment: `Textbox1.Text` **is** a string, so a simple string variable will work.  `Dim s As String = Textbox1.Text`.  Note that `Val` doesnt "hold" a value but converts the string to a value, and it always returns a `Double` not integer.  Use `Convert.ToInt32` or `CInt` to convert to integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Textbox1.Text` **is** a string, so a simple string variable will work:

```
Dim s As String = Textbox1.Text
```

But, note that `Val` doesnt "hold" a value but is a function to convert a string to a value.  And it always returns a `Double`, not `Integer`.

To convert a string to `Integer` use `Convert.ToInt32` or `CInt`.  When working with TextBoxes though where the user may enter illegal data such as `"123foo45"`, you should test the contents to avoid an error:

```
Dim n As Integer
If Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, n) Then
    ' text can parse, n holds the value
Else
    ' tell the user they entered bad info
End If
```